# option not recognized error while installing pythonnet

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python.net

I'm trying to install pythonnet via **pip install pythonnet** but accord error shown here:

```
Collecting pythonnet
  Using cached pythonnet-2.4.0.tar.gz (1.8 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pythonnet
  Building wheel for pythonnet (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/paziresh/virtualenv/paziresh365/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-jcvixpk5/pythonnet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-jcvixpk5/pythonnet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-ig8_5h8m
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-jcvixpk5/pythonnet/
  Complete output (43 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  /bin/sh: mono: command not found
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-jcvixpk5/pythonnet/setup.py", line 658, in <module>
      zip_safe=False,
    File "/home/paziresh/virtualenv/paziresh365/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 161, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-jcvixpk5/pythonnet/setup.py", line 610, in run
      return bdist_wheel.bdist_wheel.run(self)
    File "/home/paziresh/virtualenv/paziresh365/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-jcvixpk5/pythonnet/setup.py", line 245, in build_extension
      self._install_packages()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-jcvixpk5/pythonnet/setup.py", line 424, in _install_packages
      subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=use_shell)
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'mono tools/nuget/nuget.exe update -self' returned non-zero exit status 127.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pythonnet
  Running setup.py clean for pythonnet
Failed to build pythonnet
Installing collected packages: pythonnet
    Running setup.py install for pythonnet ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/paziresh/virtualenv/paziresh365/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-jcvixpk5/pythonnet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-jcvixpk5/pythonnet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install--record /tmp/pip-record-uuxxm05w/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/paziresh/virtualenv/paziresh365/3.6/include/site/python3.6/pythonnet
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-jcvixpk5/pythonnet/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help

    error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/paziresh/virtualenv/paziresh365/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-jcvixpk5/pythonnet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-jcvixpk5/pythonnet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-uuxxm05w/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/paziresh/virtualenv/paziresh365/3.6/include/site/python3.6/pythonnet Check the logs for full command output.
```

made some searches and found required libs are wheel, setuptools and scons.so all of them are installed and updated. but nothing changed!
any new idea about that?

> - I'm using python 3.6.8 and Linux

Comment: Which distro do you use?

Comment: `/bin/sh: mono: command not found` indicates that you have to install `mono` first.